# Android AVD Emulator missing letters/elements

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, android-virtual-device

My emulator does not show as correctly. It misses some letters and elements. I tried with other Android versions and it has the same issue. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Mine also shows missing elements!
[image]